# How does ISP know when to change the dynamic IP?

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp, isp

As I understand, ISP uses DHCP protocol to give out IPs from some pool. Every time they give the IP via DHCP it has a lease time. At the end of a lease time, a router can receive the same IP - but it doesn't have to.

Now, consider this situation: I am in a middle of uploading a file to some server or I'm connected to it via SSH or TCP. But the IP lease time is up and the ISP's DHCP decides to give me a **different** IP address. That would break my SSH/TCP connection to the server or interrupt uploading a file, right?

This doesn't really happen in practice. **So my question is**: does ISP monitors if some packets are coming in/out of my router (=some connection is active) and if so it assigns me the same IP address at the end of the lease time?

---

**Additional question:** if the above it's true, can this be abused to "guarantee" myself a "static IP", even though I only pay for dynamic IP, for example, by pinging google every second? Or keeping some open SSH connection all the time?

Comment: “This doesn't really happen in practice.”—I question this assertion. What makes you say that? Do you know that your IP address changes because the DHCP lease expires?

Comment: @DanielB “This doesn't really happen in practice.” - this was regarding interruption of connection. What I meant is that file uploading is not interrupted or SSH connections to some servers are not broken, because ISP suddenly changes IP. I was just wondering how this is guaranteed.

Comment: I think also your used Internet connection type play a role, because on DSL and cable connection the Internet connection is terminated on logical level and the router automatically reconnects and in this process gets a new IP.

Answer (score 3):

This is described in the Wikipedia article
[[Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol),
and especially in the section about
[Reliability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Reliability):

> The DHCP ensures reliability in several ways: periodic renewal,
> rebinding,[11]: Section 4.4.5  and failover. DHCP clients are
> allocated leases that last for some period of time. Clients begin to
> attempt to renew their leases once half the lease interval has
> expired.[11]: Section 4.4.5 Paragraph 3  They do this by sending a
> unicast DHCPREQUEST message to the DHCP server that granted the
> original lease. If that server is down or unreachable, it will fail to
> respond to the DHCPREQUEST. However, in that case the client repeats
> the DHCPREQUEST from time to time,[11]: Section 4.4.5 Paragraph 8 [b]
> so if the DHCP server comes back up or becomes reachable again, the
> DHCP client will succeed in contacting it and renew the lease.
>
> If the DHCP server is unreachable for an extended period of
> time,[11]: Section 4.4.5 Paragraph 5  the DHCP client will attempt to
> rebind, by broadcasting its DHCPREQUEST rather than unicasting it.
> Because it is broadcast, the DHCPREQUEST message will reach all
> available DHCP servers. If some other DHCP server is able to renew the
> lease, it will do so at this time.
>
> In order for rebinding to work, when the client successfully contacts
> a backup DHCP server, that server must have accurate information about
> the client's binding. Maintaining accurate binding information between
> two servers is a complicated problem; if both servers are able to
> update the same lease database, there must be a mechanism to avoid
> conflicts between updates on the independent servers. A proposal for
> implementing fault-tolerant DHCP servers was submitted to the Internet
> Engineering Task Force, but never formalized.[27][c]
>
> If rebinding fails, the lease will eventually expire. When the lease
> expires, the client must stop using the IP address granted to it in
> its lease.[11]: Section 4.4.5 Paragraph 9  At that time it will
> restart the DHCP process from the beginning by broadcasting a
> DHCPDISCOVER message. Since its lease has expired, it will accept any
> IP address offered to it. Once it has a new IP address (presumably
> from a different DHCP server) it will once again be able to use the
> network. However, since its IP address has changed, any ongoing
> connections will be broken.

The answer is simply : This won't happen, because your computer and the
router will make any effort possible to hold on to their lease on
their IP.

Only if the connection to the DHCP server is disrupted for a time that
is longer than half the lease period, do you stand a chance of losing
your IP and the disruption of the ongoing upload/download.

In practical terms, such a disruption means that your ISP is
partially or fully down, so your upload/download is likely
to have other problems than just losing its IP, and much before
the lease runs out.

Comment: This is correct, but to the OP's question there is no guarantee.  The ISP can change their pools, settings, whatnots.  Nothing is life is guaranteed.

Comment: @Keltari: Correct. If we're into Philosophy, there is also this one : Sh*t happens.

Comment: Thanks, harrymc, but my public IP changes from time to time (every couple of days) and from your answer it looks like that would happen only in case of some failure (like DHCP inaccessible for a long time). I don't think my ISP has these problems and my router is also not being reset or anything, yet it gets a different IP from time to time. So why or how that happens? Half the lease time has passed, the router requested DHCPREQUEST and ISP's DHCP server just responded with a different IP?

Comment: What you describe seems like a policy by your ISP to limit your lease time. Perhaps as an incentive for buying a static IP?

Answer (score 0):

The ISP monitors every packet coming from your router because it has to route them to the right destination.

**But** that doesn't have anything to do with the IP lease. DHCP leases are not implemented on your IP address (which is layer 3) but on your layer 2 address. In laymen's term's: your ISP knows your layer 2 address, as long as the same layer 2 address requests a new IP the DHCP server will give out the same IP address as long as a lease is valid. If the lease expires (and gets deleted) you will get the next available IP address from the pool, this can be your old one, but it usually isn't.

In regards to your additional question, no you can not prolong your lease time, but you could try to do the reconnect as soon as possible so you will be still reconnecting within the lease time. But note, on most consumer internet connections the lease time is so short, that reconnecting will always give you a new IP and usually there is a forced reconnect after 24 hours.